# Postgreql wal archive keeps failing: archive command failed with exit code 1

Tags: postgresql, transaction-log

I have a file that keeps failing to archive.

**The failed archive command was: test ! -f /mnt/wal_archive/archivedir/00000001000003F000000072 && cp pg_wal/00000001000003F000000072 /mnt/wal_archive/archivedir/00000001000003F000000072**

As instructed in other questions, I already manually deleted the file manually on the archivedir, and the file was copied again automatically, once that occurs, I start seeing the fail command again.

At the moment the file is in the **pg_wal** and in the **archivedir**. Once the file is in the **archivedir** shouldn't it be removed from from the **pg_wal**?

I'm a bit lost and out of ideas, any help would be appreciated. thanks

**UPDATE:
This is all I get from the logs**

DETAIL: The failed archive command was: test ! -f /mnt/wal_archive/archivedir/00000001000003F000000072 && cp pg_wal/00000001000003F000000072 /mnt/wal_archive/archivedir/00000001000003F000000072

Error
2022-05-12 09:54:29.207 CEST2022-05-12 07:54:29.206 UTC [18] LOG: archive command failed with exit code 1

Error
2022-05-12 09:54:29.207 CEST2022-05-12 07:54:29.206 UTC [18] DETAIL: The failed archive command was: test ! -f /mnt/wal_archive/archivedir/00000001000003F000000072 && cp pg_wal/00000001000003F000000072 /mnt/wal_archive/archivedir/00000001000003F000000072

Error
2022-05-12 09:54:29.207 CEST2022-05-12 07:54:29.207 UTC [18] WARNING: archiving write-ahead log file "00000001000003F000000072" failed too many times, will try again later

**2nd Update:**

Furthermore the wal_keep_segments and the max_wal_size settings are being ignored.

Comment: Please show more of the log.

Comment: The `test` is there to reduce the odds of two servers accidentally overwriting each others files if they are pointed to the same archive location.  If you are sure that can't happen (or if you will just blindly delete the files anyway), you can remove the whole `test` command.

Comment: There's no more log on kubernetes. Only that the command fails. Where can I get extra logs? Once I deleted the file, it was copied again, so I assume the test executed properly as the && cp, So I assume the error is not there.

Comment: Any suggestions?